# Back up windows server 2008 to external disk

Tags: windows-backup, backup

I've got a windows server 2008 box that I want to backup (the entire disk) to external USB hard drives (I've got 2 lying around so I can swap between them and add more over time).

I've tried using the built in backup tool with windows, which worked for the USB disk I had mounted at the time, but won't let me use the other one, since it seems to be associated with the first one. Is there a way to do this, or am I looking at other tools?

Thanks

Comment: how big is the disk on the windows server box? How big are the external drives?

Comment: The external disks are big enough for a backup from the server - theres not that much on there. Like I said I can get it working for one of the disks, but I can't "swap" them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, sussed it. You can indeed add multiple backup disks to in the built in tool (Windows Server Backup). Once you've set up and configured it to use the current usb disk, you can modify the backup config and choose "Add new backup disk". Plug in the other USB disk, select it as a backup device, and then you can backup to that device too - just swap them out to your hearts content.